# Strange Android Permissions Issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

I recently decided to provide haptic feedback for the buttons in my app.  I looked up how to get the Vibrator from the activity and arranged for my button object to call vibrate().

Truth be told, the first time around, I had in fact forgotten to set the permission android.permission.VIBRATE, but I quickly put that into the manifest once the exception was thrown.

The problem is that the app continues to throw a security exception claiming the app does not have the VIBRATE permission.  I've uninstalled the app on the test phone.  I've done a clean build of the project, even restarted Eclipse just for giggles, but nothing makes this exception go away.

Can anyone think of a reason why this would happen?

Comment: I have no idea what happened, but it's working now.  It's absolutely inexplicable.

Answer (score 0):

The only time this has ever happened to me, it was due to Eclipse creating bad APKs. Maybe try deleting your bin folder entirely and then rebuild?

Also, I double check your manifest to be absolutely sure you spelled the permission properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you used `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>` and not just `<uses-permission name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`?